# Is there a nodejs alert() function? how it exists in react-native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

In the browser, the browser provides an API called `window.alert()`.

The `alert()` method makes a popup in the browser to take the user attention towards the popup box:

[image]

That happens in the world of the web.

Where the global containing object is the Window object.

We call this **the global scope**.

Now, the question is actually regarding **react-native**.

Since React Native actually runs *over Node.js*, how this function exists and even works when Node.js **has no** `alert()` method defined in the "module scope".!

If you try to run Node.js with `alert()`, it will throw an error! See the image below:

[image]

My confusion is, with react-native, we don't have `<div />`, `<input />` and `<p />`,
instead, we have `<View />`, `<TextField />` and `<Text />`.

So how was Nodejs smart enough to guess that we're using React Native and that the `alert()` which is a web API method corresponds to something like this - on Android:

[image]

`alert()` isn't a component syntax coming from react-native, like `<Alert />`, it's just a function like any function, like `String()`, `parseInt()`, `Math.random()` and so on.

We don't import it.

Is react-native *prepossessing* the text we write in our **.js** files and searches for the word `alert()` then it converts it to `<Alert />`?

Comment: why do you think it (react native) is "smart". developers just named the function over the function in web

Comment: @YehorAndrosov, I edited the last part in my question.

Comment: `Since React Native actually runs over Node.js` - This is wrong. React Native runs on iOS or Android, not node.js. While it's possible to install node.js on Android it is currently not possible to install node.js on iOS because it breaks Apples TOS.

Comment: alert is part of Alert class - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ea85b313541c9d08b53854c2335817c12db53201/packages/react-native/Libraries/Alert/Alert.js#L43
i am not sure what are reasons behind this design. my guess is that it calls native component that is outside of the rendering engine -> no reason to wrap it into react component

Comment: @YehorAndrosov,  so Is react-native prepossessing the text we write in our .js files and searches for the word alert() then it converts it to <Alert />?

Comment: @Normal Not preprocessing. React Native is it's own kind of browser-like environment, not a headless (console) interpreter like node.js. It's kind of the same like what happens if you call `alert()` in the browser. Does the browser pre-process your js files and replace alert with it's built-in widget? No. It implements the `alert()` function. Similarly React Native also implement its own alert

Answer (score 0):

> Since React Native actually runs over Node.js,

It doesn't. React Native uses Node.js to run its build tools. The programs you write in React Native run on, typically, [Hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment).

Comment: Can you make more explanation on how all these things are connected to each other. And where does is Hermes fits in? Instead of the v8 engine?.

Comment: @Normal Hermes is React Native's javascript interpreter. You can compare it to V8 or JavascriptCore (Safari and bun's js interpreter)